# Mozilla Firefox Mobile add-on for script blocking

Tags: android, javascript, firefox

I'm using Mozilla Firefox Mobile for Android and I like it :)

I already use uBlock Origin in order to get rid of ads and invasive ads.

However I would like some plugin able to prevent unwanted JavasSript from loading and maybe even take advantages of unsolved or 0-day vulnerabilities present in the browser.

Basically I'm searching for something like [NoScript](https://noscript.net/) (I wonder why the author still didn't make a port for Mozilla Firefox for Android) but that has an auto-management of the allowed domain based of their trustness.

Something like enable all Google ones except for Google Analytics, disable the ad-related domains and allow some CDN in order to make them to work.

Could you suggest me something?

Answer (score 1):

Sure: I'm using ***NoScript*** for that in Firefox on the Desktop. The same addon is, according to AMO, also [available for mobile Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/mobile/addon/noscript/). As you already mention you're "searching for something like Noscript", this should match perfectly. As of now, it was last updated January 8, 2016 – so it's up-to-date and maintained.

For those not familiar with *NoScript:*

> Allow active content to run only from sites you trust, and protect yourself against XSS and Clickjacking attacks.

By default, *NoScript* disables JavaScript on all sites except those you're explicitly enabling it. You can enable JS for sites permanently or temporarily (per session).

Comment: It seems that NoScript is available for a so called Firefox Mobile, I checked but is not the same thing of "Firefox Browser for Android". It's not listed if i try to search the add-on and if I use the direct link the install doesn't work :\

Comment: Strange. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox_for_mobile), that should be the very same: *Firefox for mobile is available for Android devices running Android version 2.3 and above.* German Wikipedia even goes a step further saying (raw translation) "Firefox mobile currently is only available for Android." You see me quite confused. Admittedly, I'm not using FF on Android. Maybe someone else has a clue here – or I shall have to remove my answer as not fitting then.

Comment: Additionally see this: [NoScript :: Versions :: Add-ons für Firefox für Android](https://addons.mozilla.org/De/android/addon/noscript/versions/). I cant get this page for EN, but in German it explicitly states: "Add-ons for Firefox on Android". Wait, here it is in EN: [NoScript Security Suite :: Versions :: Add-ons for Firefox for Android](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/android/addon/noscript/versions/). And now? ?-/

Comment: I have no idea but it seems not to work. I have firefox for android on 2 phones pretty new here and i tried to search the android addon, i can't find it :( If i use the direct link it says download but doesn't install.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention already using uBlock Origin ("uBO"), you could enable advanced user mode, block all 3rd-party scripts by default, then create global `noop` rules for the domains you trust: that would be what I call [medium mode](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/Blocking-mode:-medium-mode) in uBO.

You can use the *My rules* pane in the dashboard to manually create your rules, and even import them from RequestPolicy or NoScript. For example, a rule to trust `google.com` would be `* google.com * noop`.

Comment: I have to try it but I would like something with already a whitelist activable so i have not to do it manually (thing that on a phone is not easy).